# Not Able To Generate TrueType Font Metrics

Tags: fonts, apache-fop, truetype

I am new to this FOP, XSLT; here I am trying to generate the TTF metrics from an .ttf file from linux box.
Had tried with fop-2.8 and fop-1.1

With fop-1.1 had ran below command:

```
exec java -cp build/fop.jar;lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar;lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;lib/xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar;lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader -fn /user/sample.ttf sample.xml
```

With fop-2.8 :
I see most of the above jars are not present there inside lib so how we can create the font metrics file with fop-2.8?

Again for fop-1.1 seems command is not recognized buy fop; getting usages options

```
$ exec java -cp build/fop.jar;lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar;lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;lib/xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar;lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader -fn /user/sample.ttf sample.xml
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)

 Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
 -m or --module <module>/<mainclass> are passed as the arguments to
 main class.
```

<<<***Update***>>>

For fop-1.1 also tried below command :

```
$ java -cp build/fop.jar;lib/avalon-framework*.jar;lib/commons-logging*.jar;lib/commons-io*.jar org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader /path/to/sample.ttf /path/to/sample.xml
```

source:  https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/fonts.html

Still same getting below in console:

```
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)

 Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar[1]: PK^C^D: not found [No such file or directory]
lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar: syntax error at line 2: `zero byte' unexpected
lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar[1]: PK^C^D: not found [No such file or directory]
lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar: syntax error at line 2: `zero byte' unexpected
lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar[1]: PK^C^D: not found [No such file or directory]
lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar: syntax error at line 2: `zero byte' unexpected
```

But I have below:

```
$ ls -lart lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 group usr 38015 Oct 17  2012 lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 group usr 83613 Oct 17  2012 lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 group usr 81961 Oct 17  2012 lib/avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
```

So not sure what it does mean, will be helpful if I can get any fruitful input regarding same.

Comment: Note that if you are using a recent version of FOP you don't need font metrics any more to configure fonts.

Comment: avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar is that the jar from fop-1.1 that was needed for generating these area tree xml?

Comment: Area tree xml (a different form of output file, instead of a pdf) and font metrics (a file once needed to configure fonts) are completely different things ... it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: Ok I rechecked my bad I was trying to generate font metrics using that command ; so avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar is that the jar from fop-1.1 that was needed for generating these font metrics ?